# regex help on searching a string for a match

Tags: java, regex

What I need to do is check a string and this is what I have so far

```
System.out.print("Please enter a string of 1's and 0s :");
numLine = input.next();

if (numLine.matches("^101$")) {
    System.out.print("A is true");
} else if (numLine.matches("^\\d[01]+101$ ")){
    System.out.print("B is true");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");  
}
```

The first part of the code the ^101$ works and prints out A is true
for B what I am trying to do is only accept 1s and 0s and return if it ends in 101
and I would like a C to do 101 at the begining and accept as many 1s and 0s
and a D that does 101 anywhere in it even if its 111000101000 or something else

the killer for me is the ("^101$") syntax and I could use help with that

Comment: You don't need `^` and `$` with `matches`.

Comment: What did you intend for the `\d` in the second regex to mean?

Comment: well the initial idea was to be able to take strings and that is set up but if the string is "101" it returns A if its "0100101" it would return B, "101001001" would get C, and "111000101000111" would return D. At the same time it rejects everything but 1s and 0s.

Comment: what I mean is that the second regex you put `\\d` at the beginning. That matches a single instance of any digit. This does not seem to be what you are asking, so I was wondering why you had it in there

Comment: in that case it was me trying to figure out what one sheet said I found on regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `^` and `$` with `matches` (as I said in my comment). Here's the way I see it:

**B:** `"[01]+101"`
**C:** `"101[01]+"`
**D:** `"[01]*101[01]*"`

---

Recall that `X+` means `X` *one or more times* and that `X*` means `X` *zero or more times*.

Also (for **A**), if you want to 'match' only `"101"`, you might want to consider simply using `equals` instead, i.e. `numLine.equals("101")`.

Answer (score 1):

The four regular expressions you want are very similar:

To match exactly "101" (A), as you found, use `101` (as mentioned in the comments, you don't need to use `^` and `$`.

To match anything that ends with "101" (B), use `[01]*101`.

To match anything that begins with "101" (C), use `101[01]*`.

To match anything that contains "101" (D), use `[01]*101[01]*`.

In all cases, `[01]*` means 0 or more instances of any character in the set {0,1}, so each of these looks for `101` with the rest of the string filled out as applicable with only `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you wanted to do, but I understood what you wanted regex for, so I'll simply post that.

A - `^101$` matches `101` as the whole string.

B - `^101` matches `101` at the beginning of a string. Add `[10]*` after, to include `0` and `1` after. `^101[10]*`

C - `101$` matches `101` at the end of a string. Add `[10]*^` at the beginning to include preceding `0` and `1`. `[10]*101$`

D - `101` matches `101` anywhere.